# More than one toggle button causes app to crash

Tags: java, android, xml

I have 2 toggle buttons. The first one "on_off_toggle_button" works fine. But once I press the second one the app crashes. The first button will work fine and do it's thing but the second one always crashes the app regardless if it's doing any or not. If I swap it so the second button has the onClick action I still get a crash. I think it's something to do with the toggle itself but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Anyone know why this is?

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:background="@drawable/border_line"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_padding"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_padding"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/on_off_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_vertical_padding"
        android:text="Off/On"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/on_off_toggle_button"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="37dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/toggle_selector"
        android:checked="false"
        android:onClick="startLockScreenService"
        android:text=""
        android:textOff=""
        android:textOn="" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:background="@drawable/border_line"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_padding"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_padding"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <TextView

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_vertical_padding"
        android:text="Off/On"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/on_offnotif_button"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="37dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/toggle_selector2"
        android:checked="false"
        android:onClick=""
        android:text=""
        android:textOff=""
        android:textOn="" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what is the logcat put logcat here to better help

Comment: empty `android:onClick=""`

Comment: I'll have to get back to with that in an hour so, my office computer doesn't allow emulations for whatever reason so I'll have to do it at home.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45355687/more-than-one-toggle-button-causes-app-to-crash/45355852#comment77672761_45355687) : there is an empty `android:onClick=""` handler so when you click then OS will not be able to find any handler and an exception will be thrown

Solution

Either add a corresponding handler function like you did with other `ToggleButton`

OR **remove** `android:onClick=""` and then you can initialize your button and bind listener using anonymous class

Answer (score 2):

You have registered for an empty name of `OnClickListener`

```
android:onClick=""
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `android:onClick=""` is empty.